# Troubleshoot cause of application Java error

Tags: java

I'm trying to see why our legacy Java application (by 3rd party) no longer works after Server upgrade (and reinstalling all Java jdk,jre,etc). All JavaHome are OK. This application should produce html out of xml files.
Running on Windows 2012 R2 Standard.

Understand this could be very generic, but at least probably can eliminate some causes, so I can find right people, I'm DBA and dealing with this myself.  I pasted error log below, if anybody can point me to some causes, it works with SQL Server, I can see some ports number (:4098) which are not relevant to SQL Server, afraid it somehow deal with Oracle vs SQL server, this app works OK with both, having selector on UI.

```
    Java installed:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
    jdk1.8.0_151
    jre1.8.0_231
    [![ImagePrograms][1]][1]jre7


echo %JAVA_HOME%
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_231   


 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler (file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/AlphaGX/
    .6.1.jar) to method com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser$LocatorProxy.getEncoding()
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.dom4j.io.SAXContentHandler
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4098)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3160)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:43)
            at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3123)
```

Comment: It looks like you are using Java 9+

Comment: Dz M!  I Think  I need to install it, right ?.

Comment: Read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/516167

Comment: No, you have probably already installed it and your application is using this newer version instead of Java8.

Comment: I now restarted  from clean uninstall all and installing most recent, but still don't see updates in Java dir, I put updates in post.  Still only jre7

Comment: If not work ,then I'll try go back to 8

Comment: The error means that a class from JAXB is missing. JAXB is not enabled / included anymore by default in Java 9 and newer. See https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/ for a detailed description.

Comment: You **need** to go back to Java 8. Your application is not compatible with Java 9 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

Your legacy application was run on Java 9 or newer. It failed because it is not compatible with newer Java versions.

Please run it on Java 8 instead.